# Fixed Div Stop At Certain Point jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my fixed div to stop scrolling at a certain point on my webpage, however, none of the solutions I have found have actually functioned properly and done what I've wanted...

This is my current jQuery:

```
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this, $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                bottom: -10px
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#qF').followTo(800);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="qF" class="central theater-dir-adown">
    <img src="data/img/prefs/dir_adown" class="dir-adown">
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.theater-dir-adown{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: calc(100% / 2 - 51px);
    width: calc(75% / 9);
    height: auto;
}

.dir-adown{
    width: 100%;
}
```

So what I want is the div `#qF` to stop scrolling at 800px, but the code that I'm using isn't working and the div will continue to scroll down the page. I'm not sure if there is some sort of error in my code but could someone please help me out? Still very new to jQuery..

Thanks

Comment: remove the `;` from `bottom: -10px;`

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh didn't work, sorry to say :( still not functioning as it should

Comment: remove `px` from `bottom: -10px` it throw error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. working: http://output.jsbin.com/latuji

Comment: @MoshFeu that didn't do anything :(

Comment: @MoshFeu that jsbin did not function correctly

Comment: please add a jsfiddle link

Comment: `that jsbin did not function correctly` why not? What's wrong?

Comment: @MoshFeu it was very glitchy and the image would disappear after hitting 800px and if it did show, it would appear at the default position

Answer (score 1):

add top:'auto' when setting position to fixed

```
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this, $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                bottom: -10,
                top:'auto'
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#qF').followTo(800);
```

you can add top: pos + $(window).height() to start scrolling from bottom

http://jsbin.com/fuzutaxiha/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: did you see the jsbin link?! the img is fixed to bottom till scroll rich the 800 px height, then it scrolls to top, it is not what you wanted?

Comment: the JSBin is working fine, however, It is not working with my code